# Javascript + Vue error: array.filter not working as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two arrays:

- `$globalData.dishes` defined in `main.js` as `['Salad', 'Burger', 'Cake']`.
- `dishes` defined in `App.vue` as an empty array.

The code I've written should list all dishes in `$globalData.dishes` originally in pink. When a dish is clicked, it is added to `dishes` and its color changes to green (this works). When clicked on again it is removed from `dishes` and its color reverts back to pink **(this does not work)**.

---

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Dishes:</h2>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="dish in this.$globalData.dishes" v-bind:key="dish.id"
      :style="[dishes.includes(dish) ? 
      {'background-color': 'lightgreen'} :
      {'background-color': 'pink'}]"
      @click="addDish(dish)">
      {{ dish }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      dishes: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addDish(dish){
      if (this.dishes.includes(dish)){
        this.dishes.filter((d) => d !== dish)
      } else {
        this.dishes.push(dish);
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

main.js:

```
...
Vue.prototype.$globalData = Vue.observable({
  dishes: ['Salad', 'Burger', 'Cake'],
});
...
```

Comment: You need to update your addDish method to correctly remove the dish from the array. Filter method doesn't modify the original array, it creates a new one for you, but you are not assigning that new value to your this.dishes

Comment: @ChrisG that's it! Feel free to add that as an answer (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is with the `addDish` method in your `App.vue` component.

The `Array.filter` method doesn't modify the original array, it creates a new array. Therefore, when you try to remove a dish by using `this.dishes.filter()` method, it creates a new array, but you are not assigning it back to this.dishes.

You need to update your `addDish` method to correctly remove the dish from the array.

```
methods: {
    addDish(dish){
      if (this.dishes.includes(dish)){
        this.dishes = this.dishes.filter((d) => d !== dish);
      } else {
        this.dishes.push(dish);
      }
    },
  }
```